# Why is my fan continuously running when A/C is selected?

Tags: thermostat

I bought a home with a honeywell TB8220U1003 thermostat that automatically turns heat on and off with no issues if I have the setting (switch) on my furnace set to heat. In order for my cool to be activated, I need to manually switch my furnace from heat to vent (electric furnace). By doing this, my blower/fan runs continuously even though I have the fan setting on the thermostat and the furnace set to auto. Why won't the thermostat control the fan with the cool setting the same way as the heat? I am grasping at straws here and frustrated, the thermostat is supposed to do the work for me....please help if you can.
It is too dark outside at the moment to provide the make and model of my A/C unit but my furnace is  Chaudair, Federal Pioneer, Model NCEF-15, manufactured in October 1987 (electric). From the little research I have done, I believe I am running a 1H/1C conv unit.Is this something that I will just have to live with or is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the fan is programmed to be on when in cooling mode. See the programming guide for the TB8220 section “fan schedule” it’s on page 18 of the manual I found. With fan in on it runs all the time, auto only when needed then there are other settings , occ1, unocc1, occ2 and unocc2 , other than this there is a manual override of the fan schedule, so if it runs fine in heat mode but you don’t like the choice in cooling mode you will need to reprogram the thermostat, note if I install a electrostatic filter in a home the default setting to keep the pollen and dust free in the summer is on all the time so I would check for an electrostatic filter just prior to the air handler, if you have one they need to be washed down every month or so based on how much your unit is picking up, once the grid wires are full they don’t catch the dust and pollen, I put the grid in the shower and a hot water rinse is all that is normally needed, if there are smokers in the home a spray with simple green will cut the tar but it may take 2 cycles to get nice clean wires. Let air dry then reinstall, note even with an electrostatic filter there should be at minimum a fiberglass filter prior to the electrostatic to pick up the big particles.